Highly composite numbers which are the middle of a twin prime
From the first $10\ 000$ highly composite numbers listed in OEIS , the following $20$ are the middle of a twin-prime that is we have a highly composite number $N$ such that both $N-1$ and $N+1$ are prime (the second number denotes the number of decimal digits) :
4  1
6  1
12  2
60  2
180  3
240  3
7560  4
55440  5
110880  6
73329656400  11
18632716502400  14
130429015516800  15
48519593772249600  17
149602080797769600  18
74377068101903920953600  23
927967188666725711881005276648000  33
241271469053348685089061371928480000  36
50739595324912050170305529996630230464563024879813409718878962795046826080000  77
12727444456877128729707334701266041789227838550123680669847107058667285355888857766968473763984052605329540082484932027447083953720691475664535040000  149
40264192094444092677941997983243514442222809383085958285415146297268942398430079681279760167882364623816604246021540122485381934104407260095942212267331346400748497233108480000  176

From the $400$ displayed superhighly composite numbers in OEIS , only the following $4$ have this property :
6  1
12  2
60  2
55440  5


What are the next known such numbers in both cases ?


It's not clear what the "this property" is that the second group features.

@KeithBackman Being the middle of a twin prime.

My bad. I failed to notice that the groups differ between "highly composite" and "superhighly composite"

When are highly composite numbers not of form 6(6ab+a+b),  6(6ab-a-b) , or 6(6ab+a-b) basically
